# How to get id of slider for get slider_group?

Tags: laravel

I have two tables `sliders` and `slider_group`.

In my controller in create function in laravel, I want the get the id that shows in browser show when I browse it shows like this.

> http://localhost:8000/admin/sliders/create/21

blade

```
<a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.create', ['groupId', $sliderGroup->id]) }}" class="mr-1">
```

Now how to get the id of `slider_group` table to group_id of requisitions.

```
<tbody>
@foreach($sliderGroups as $sliderGroup)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-truncate">
            <i class="la la-dot-circle-o success font-medium-1 mr-1"></i>
            {{ $sliderGroup->id }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-wrap">
            {{ $sliderGroup->title }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-wrap">
            {{ getShamsiDate($sliderGroup->created_at) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.create', ['groupId', $sliderGroup->id]) }}" class="mr-1">
                    <i class="la la-plus text-grey text-shadow-custom font-medium-4 font-weight-normal"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="{{ route('admin::slider-groups.edit', $sliderGroup->id) }}" class="mr-1">
                    <i class="ft-edit text-grey text-shadow-custom font-medium-4 font-weight-normal"></i>
                </a>
                <form action="{{ route('admin::slider-groups.destroy', $sliderGroup) }}" method="post" @submit.prevent="confirmDelete">
                    @method('delete')
                    @csrf
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default p-0">
                        <i class="ft-trash-2 text-grey font-medium-5 font-weight-normal"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I get this in address bar like this

> http://localhost:8000/admin/sliders/create?groupId&3

It has an error.

> 404 | Not Found

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->search) {
        $sliderGroups = SliderGroup::search($request->search)->paginate(30);
    } else {
        $sliderGroups = SliderGroup::paginate(30);
    }
    if ($sliderGroups->count() == 0 && $request->search ) {
        msg()->warning('it is not found.');
    }
    return view('slider::admin.groups.index', compact('sliderGroups'));
}
```

web.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as'     => 'admin::',
], function() {
    Route::resource('sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
    Route::resource('slider-groups', 'Admin\SliderGroupController');
});
```

Comment: attach pls  `route.php`

Comment: I added route.php

Comment: you can do it like this `$request->query('groupId');`

Comment: in where? in the blade.php?

Comment: yes in controller

Comment: I changed this, but my problem did not sole yet

Comment: I updated my post...

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?